# Error in requiring Sinatra gem

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, sinatra, ubuntu-9.10

I'm having a hard time getting Sinatra running on my local setup, Ubuntu Karmic 9.10. The error getting thrown when I have require 'sinatra' is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:891:in `compile'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:883:in `gsub'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:883:in `compile'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:856:in `route'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:838:in `get'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1077
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:929:in `configure'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1076
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra.rb:4
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from (irb):2
from :0
```

I've tried:

- Uninstalling/reinstalling Sinatra
- Updating all gems
- Ensuring all dependencies exist (rack)

Any ideas? Your time and help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What was the first line seen by irb?

Comment: What version of ruby are you running?

Comment: `Error requiring Sinatra Gem` that's because it's gone: http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1350&dat=19521204&id=XXkTAAAAIBAJ&sjid=ZwAEAAAAIBAJ&pg=5568,1086650 (I hope the link holds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue apparently only coming up with 1.8-head on Linux. It is related to regexp matching. If you take a look in the code: `path` does match `/((:\w+)|[\*#{special_chars.join}])/`, but `$2` is `nil`, even though it is supposed to be a String.

I recommend switching your ruby version for now.

Comment: Thank you - changing to ruby 1.8.7 seems to have fixed it.